# Converting JODA UTC time to timezone

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Using the following block of code I am trying to convert a UTC JODA time to a specified timezone using a string vale, e.g "Asia/Tokyo"

```
 public void handleTimezoneConversion(TimesheetEntry timesheetEntry, String timezone) {

        System.out.println("TO :"+timezone);
        System.out.println(timesheetEntry.getStartDateTime());

        LocalDateTime startDateTime = timesheetEntry.getStartDateTime();
        startDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone));
        timesheetEntry.setStartDateTime(startDateTime);

        System.out.println(timesheetEntry.getStartDateTime());
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = timesheetEntry.getEndDateTime();
        endDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone));
        timesheetEntry.setEndDateTime(endDateTime);


}
```

When i run it the time stays the same evn though there should be a noticeable difference.

Where am I going wrong, are my methods off course completely?

Answer (score 0):

LocalDateTime's toDateTime() method returns a DateTime.  In your code, you're calling toDateTime() but discarding the return value.  Instead, you'll want to do something like this:

```
DateTime newDateTime = startDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, when I sub in that line I get the following:

2014-09-08T08:45:00.000+09:00

I wanted the time to be 17:45, how do i do this?